# How to prevent last child from being destroyed unless parent is destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

We have 2 simple models where a `workspace` has many `memberships`. We need to prevent the last `membership` from being destroyed *unless* it's `workspace` is destroyed.

This code isn't letting us destroy memberships when we destroy the workspace -- could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to do this?

```
class Workspace < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :workspace, counter_cache: true
  before_destroy :ensure_one_member, unless: -> { workspace.destroyed? }
  
  private
  def ensure_one_member
    raise "Can't delete the last member" if workspace.memberships.count == 1
  end
end
```

```
% rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.2.2)
irb(main):001:0> Workspace.last.destroy
  Workspace Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "workspaces".* FROM "workspaces" ORDER BY "workspaces"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN                                  
  Membership Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" WHERE "memberships"."workspace_id" = $1  [["workspace_id", 3]]
  Membership Count (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "memberships" WHERE "memberships"."workspace_id" = $1  [["workspace_id", 3]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK                               
/Users/vince/code/myapp/app/models/membership.rb:6:in `ensure_one_member': Can't delete the last member (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be creating a new Error instance here to trigger an exception? Could be wrong but I think you need `raise Error.new "Can't delete the last member"` and remove the unless condition on the before_destroy callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fas as i know, rollback occurs because rails trying to delete `Members` before `Workspace` so `ensure_one_member` still triggered even when you try to destroy `Workspace`. It's not a perfect but `destroyed_by_association` check may solve your problem. Youn can check related discussion [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12828#issuecomment-28142715)

Comment: didn't know about this! I replaced the code to `before_destroy :ensure_one_member, unless: :destroyed_by_association` and it's working great